# ios, objectivc-c, AD Hoc Deployment, Distribution profile issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad, ipod

When I create build using AD Hoc Deployment (for Development profile) it installs in all my devices (4s,ipod,5c), On the other hand When I create build using AD Hoc Deployment (for Distribution profile)for same project , It installs only in my 5c iPhone ,but failed all other device (4s,ipod). Why it is happening. Thanks in advance.

Comment: iOS version on 4s and iPod ?

Comment: iOS version on 4s "8.1"      iPod = "8.2"     and  5c is = "8.1"

Comment: Try deleting the old AdHoc profiles from 4s and iPod, I hope it will work then, because if devices are added properly in the profile then it should work.

Comment: Thanks @ Omer, Let me check and I will give you update.

Answer (score 0):

Could be may reasons but follow these steps hope that works

1. Check if all your device's `UDID` is included in the provisioning
         profile.
2. Download the new provisioning (make sure it's adhoc). Delete the old one and install the new one.
3. Check the deployment target and the iOS version of your devices.
4. Clean your project and delete the derive data.
5. Select valid provisioning profile and distribution certificate.
6. Archive your product
7. Install your build now.

Comment: Thanks @ Inder, Firstly, there is need to add device's UDID for Distribution profile, furthermore I did your steps , still problem coming .

Comment: You were talking about the adhoc profile, for adhoc you need to have `UDID`'s in provisioning profile

Comment: Okay @ Inder, please let me know, any other solution for my this issue if you know.

Comment: Are you able to use these devices for development ?

Comment: Yes, When I create build using AD Hoc Deployment (for Development profile) it installs in all my devices (4s,  ipod,and 5c)